# How to use an IF-function when setting a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

It not possible to write

```
STRINGA = "NamewordStuff" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "-" & Hours(Now) & _
If Minute(Now)<10 then
    "0" & Minute(Now)
Else
    Minute(Now)
End If _
& ".xlsm"
```

How could one do this the most, I suppose, elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Iif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/iif-function):

```
STRINGA = "NamewordStuff" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "-" & Hours(Now) & _
Iif(Minute(Now)<10,    "0" & Minute(Now),    Minute(Now)) & ".xlsm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or format the number:

```
STRINGA = "NamewordStuff" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "-" & Hours(Now) & _
     Format(Minute(Now),"00") & "xlsm"
```